# Equality in the Schwarz-Pick Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to prove the following: Let be $f: \mathbb{D} \mapsto \mathbb{D}$, an analytic function. If for $z,w \in \mathbb{D}$, $z\neq w$, we have

$$
\left| \frac{f(z)-f(w)}{1- \overline{f(w)}f(z)} \right| = \left| \frac{z-w}{1 - \overline{w}z} \right|,
$$
then we have this equality for any pair of distinct points in the disk.

This my work so far:

I consider the following function:

$$
\varphi (\zeta) = B_{f(w)} \circ f \circ B_w (\zeta)
$$
where $B_w(\zeta) := \frac{w - \zeta}{1-\overline{w}\zeta},~  \text{and}~ \tau_{f(w)} (\zeta) := \frac{f(w) - \zeta}{1-\overline{f(w)}\zeta}, ~\zeta \in \mathbb{D} $. Those fucntions are Blaschke factors. $\varphi$ is clearly analytic, mapping the disk on itslef, and $\varphi (0)=0$. Also, if we suppose $z_0=B_w(z)$, we have:
\begin{align*}
|\varphi(z_0)| &= \left| B_{f(w)} \circ f \circ B_w (z_0) \right|\\
&=\left| B_{f(w)} \circ f \circ B_w \circ B_w(z) \right| \\
&=\left| B_{f(w)} \circ f(z) \right| ~~~\text{(because $B_w \circ B_w =id)$} \\
&=\left| \frac{f(z)-f(w)}{1- \overline{f(w)}f(z)} \right|\\
&= \left| \frac{z-w}{1 - \overline{w}z} \right| ~~\text{(hypothesis)}\\
&=|z_0|,
\end{align*}
we can then apply $\textit{Schwarz Lemma}$ and say that $\varphi (\zeta)=\gamma z$ where $|\gamma|=1$. Taking $\zeta=B_w(a)$, for some $a \in \mathbb{D}$ we obtain the following:
\begin{align*}
|\varphi(B_w(a))|&=\left| \frac{f(a)-f(w)}{1- \overline{f(w)}f(a)} \right|\\
&=|\gamma B_w(a)|\\
&=|\gamma| \left| \frac{a - w}{1-\overline{w}a} \right|\\
&=\left| \frac{a - w}{1-\overline{w}a} \right|.
\end{align*}

Here I proved, if i'm not wrong, that the equality works for any $z \in \mathbb{D}$ but it only works with the $w$ we started with. Any ideas how to prove that it should work for any pairs of complex numbers in the disk? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For this problem you have to know that the [Poincaré  distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_metric) between any two points  $z$, $w\in D$ is given by
$$d(z,w)={\rm artanh} \left|{z-w\over 1-\bar wz}\right|\ ,$$
and that this distance is invariant under conformal automorphisms  of $D$ (called Blaschke factors in your question). In your case you are told that a certain holomorphic function $f:\>D\to D$ satisfies 
$$d\bigl(f(z),f(w)\bigr)=d(z,w)\tag{1}$$
for a certain pair of different points $z$, $w\in D$, and it is claimed that such an $f$ automatically is a conformal automorphism of $D$.

That's where the Schwarz Lemma comes in: It is about the special case $w=f(w)=0$, and indeed says that $(1)$ for a single $z\ne0$ guarantees $f$ to be an automorphism of $D$. But any $f$ satisfying your assumption can be conjugated to a such a special $f$ by Blaschke factors (that's what you have done in your calculations). The rest is "going through the motions".

Comment: @ Christian Blatter Thanks a lot ! It was very simple to solve with your explanations.